# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /adduser from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1/4000

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am getting an error like "Internal Server Error" don't know where am wrong , please try to solve my query, I you have any query please free feel to ask.

[image: Error page]

> package.json

This is my frontend package.json file where i added proxy to communicate with backend.

```
{
  "name": "todo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1/4000/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

> user.js

This is the user.js file in their i wrote my logical part

```
const User = require("../model/userdata");

// Get All Users
exports.getAllUser = async (req, res) => {
  User.find().exec((err, users) => {
    if (err || !users) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        err: "No Users Found",
      });
    }
    res.json(users);
  });
};

// Add a single User
exports.addUser = (req, res) => {
  const user = new User(req.body);
  user.save((err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("ERROR:", err);
      return res.status(400).json({
        err: "not able to connect",
      });
    }
    res.json({
      id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      phone: user.phone,
    });
  });
};

// Get a Single User
exports.getUserById = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        err: "No User Found",
      });
    }
    res.json(user);
    console.log(user);
  });
};

// Edit User
exports.editUser = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    {
      $set: req.body,
    },
    (err, user) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          err: "User Updation Failed",
        });
      }
      res.json("User Updated Successfully");
    }
  );
};

exports.deleteUser = (req, res) => {
  let id = req.params.id;
  User.findByIdAndRemove(id, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        err: "Not able to deleted",
      });
    }
    res.json("User Deleted Succefully..");
  });
};
```

> user.js

This is the route of the user

```
const express = require("express");
const {
  getAllUser,
  addUser,
  getUserById,
  deleteUser,
  editUser,
} = require("../controller/user");

const route = express.Router();

route.get("/", getAllUser);
route.post("/adduser", addUser);
route.get("/:id", getUserById);
route.delete("/:id", deleteUser);
route.put("/:id", editUser);

module.exports = route;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message suggests, `500 Internal Server Error` there is something wrong on your server-side. You should do the debugging there. This question is not remotely related to React.

Comment: i have added the server side code now you can checkout

Comment: @TusharBhakare no idea which route you are hitting. try console logging your errors on your controller which you are hitting through your route